# Mysql search on longblob db field containing arabic text data

Tags: php, mysql

1. I want to perform search on a `LONGBLOB` field containing Arabic text data.  For example, how do U search "هذه «الأولويات الدواوينية» ف" ?

   The table field has values like `3313537353B2623313630363B2623313631303B202623313630343B2623313537353B2623313630363B202623313539303B2623313538313B2623313537353B2623313631303B2623313537353B2623313630373B2623313630353B2026`; however, if I retrieve the Arabic text value and display on a web page, it shows proper Arabic characters.
2. If I change the data type of the field from `LONGBLOB` to `LONGTEXT`, will it affect the Arabic content text I have stored? I have almost 1500 records in that table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's important to understand the difference between a *character* and its *encoding*.  The character `ن`, for example would be stored with very different bytes [depending on its encoding](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fee5/charset_support.htm).  For example, it would be represented by the single byte `0xcc` if encoded with the IBM1097 codepage, but the four byte sequence `0xfefffee5` if encoded with UTF-16.  Worse, sometimes the *same* character can be represented in multiple ways within the *same* encoding.

   Unless MySQL knows which encoding was used, it won't able to perform textual comparisons of the sort you need (whilst it *can* perform binary ones to search for the same byte sequences, this won't apply your desired *collation*—i.e. how strings are compared, e.g. case insensitivity, or different bytes sequences representing the same characters).

   Therefore you must either provide the encoding information to MySQL when you perform your search, or have MySQL keep track of it from the moment it first receives the data (i.e. by storing the data in a string-type column rather than a binary-type one).

   It is *much* more usual (and indeed I strongly advise you) to store text data in string-type columns.  `LONGTEXT` is one possibility, but might be overkill for your needs: it can store up to 4GiB of data!  Perhaps `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` (which can both hold up to 64KiB) or `MEDIUMTEXT` (up to 16MiB) would be more appropriate?

   Once understood to be character data, MySQL can simply search for text using its [String Comparison Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-comparison-functions.html) or [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html).  For example:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE textcolumn LIKE '%هذه «الأولويات الدواوينية» ف%';
   ```

   This would search `mytable` for any record whose `textcolumn` field contains (according to its collation) the specified string anywhere within it.
2. You must first understand with what encoding your existing data has been stored in the `LONGBLOB` column (which will be whatever encoding the originating client used when it inserted/updated the data).

   You can then convert it to a string-type column without problem—although note that if it differed between records, you will have to manage the conversion of each record on a case-by-case basis (but you would also face the same issue when retrieving the current data anyway).  For example, if the data is encoded using UTF-8, you can convert the column to `TEXT` as follows:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY textcolumn TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
   ```

   Note that you must ensure your [connection character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/charset-connection.html) is correctly configured for your client in order to ensure that any necessary conversions occur when sending/retrieving string data.

Comment: I made a copy of the table with longblob db field initially changed to longtext. and used this new table. search is now giving required result.

Answer (score 0):

Here are what I see as possible solutions to your two options:

**Keeping the longblob:** If you want to search for the entire content of the text, you could always do an MD5 sum (or any other hashing algorithm...whatever works for you) on the longblob and search that. You could also index this MD5 column so that you can do super fast searching if you make it a longint or something.

A problem with this approach is that you have to know the entire text content to find a record. A possible solution would be to provide subject tokens linked to the records in the table with the longblob which you could store in a separate table and search. You could then return the rows from the longblob table that match the tokens. An example would be if you had some text that talked about movies, theaters, critics, and actors you would create tokens for "movie", "theater", "critic", and "actor", store those in the token table with a foreign key to the longblob table entry containg the article, and then when a user searches for "movie" and/or "critic" and/or etc you would then return back that row in the longblob table since it matched those particular tokens. This should still give you a fast search.

**Changing to a longtext:** If you convert to use longtext it will give you better search capabilities (but slower) since you will be able to search inside. If it were me, I would create a new table with longtext as the type for the main field and write a script which reads the arabic data out of the blob and then writes it into the new table as text. If you make sure your formattings and such are correct it shouldn't corrupt your data. I am not sure if just simply converting it would corrupt it or not...you could always do a test case where you make a table with a longblob, fill it with some arabic text, and then convert the column to a long text and see what happens.

Comment: Problem with the first option is that collations can't be applied: e.g. for case insensitivity or situations where different byte sequences represent the same characters within the same encoding... therefore I wouldn't recommend doing it that way.